# The 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header contains multiple values '*, *', but only one is allowed. in Chrome and Firefox

Tags: angularjs, http, post

I am getting  Error : **The 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header contains multiple values '*, *', but only one is allowed.** while I am making Post Service call from my Application.

This is not issue with webapi service call because while I traced the call from fiddler, I am getting the **Result with 200** . But from $http.post call is throwing the error even after I am getting 200 result. I don't know why. It is working for IE but it is not working for Chrome or Firefox.

In chrome and Firefox throwing me :  **XMLHttpRequest cannot load **url**. The 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header contains multiple values '*, *', but only one is allowed. Origin **url** is therefore not allowed access.**

Please suggest which settings I need to change in Chrome and Firefox to rune.

```js
  $http.post(serviceBase + 'token', data, { headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' } }).success(function (response) {
            
            if (loginData.useRefreshTokens) {
                localStorageService.set('authorizationData', { token: response.access_token, userName: loginData.userName, refreshToken: response.refresh_token, useRefreshTokens: true });
            }
            else {
                localStorageService.set('authorizationData', { token: response.access_token, userName: loginData.userName, refreshToken: "", useRefreshTokens: false });
            }
            _authentication.isAuth = true;
            _authentication.userName = loginData.userName;
            _authentication.useRefreshTokens = loginData.useRefreshTokens;

            deferred.resolve(response);

        }).error(function (err, status) {
            _logOut();
            deferred.reject(err);
        });
```

Comment: From server side, set header as `*` instead of `*,*`

Comment: Thanks for commenting but may I know how?

Comment: I'm voting to close this, as it's been 6 years, this is a server-side issue and I'm doubtful those details will ever be supplied in this question.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using JAVA as your backend service, then you may need to apply a CORS filter to your HTTPRequests. You can do this by adding a filterClass like shown below...

```
    @Component
public class CorsFilter extends OncePerRequestFilter{
    protected static  Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(CorsFilter.class);

    protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, FilterChain filterChain)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
         logger.info("entering FILTER page");

         if (request.getHeader("Access-Control-Request-Method") != null && "OPTIONS".equals(request.getMethod())) {
            // CORS "pre-flight" request
            response.addHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
            response.addHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS");
            response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "x-requested-with");
            response.addHeader("Access-Control-Max-Age", "1800");//30 min
        }
        //This will filter your requests and responses.
        filterChain.doFilter(request, response);
    }

}
```